# How to track the memory usage of a Rust program?

Tags: rust

I know very little about Rust and I want to know the current memory usage of a Rust program.
I found [Memory Stats](https://docs.rs/memory-stats/latest/memory_stats/#memory-stats),
which might be useful. But I got following compilation error when adding memory-states to Cargo.toml

```
   Compiling memory-stats v1.1.0
error[E0432]: unresolved imports `libc::mach_task_basic_info_data_t`, `libc::mach_task_self`, `libc::task_info`, `libc::task_info_t`, `libc::MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO`, `libc::MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT`
 --> /Users/meij/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/memory-stats-1.1.0/src/darwin.rs:4:29
  |
4 |     mach_msg_type_number_t, mach_task_basic_info_data_t, mach_task_self, task_info, task_info_t, K...
  |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^ no `task_info_t` in the root
  |                             |                            |               |
  |                             |                            |               no `task_info` in the root
  |                             |                            no `mach_task_self` in the root
  |                             no `mach_task_basic_info_data_t` in the root
5 |     MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO, MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT,
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT` in the root
  |     |
  |     no `MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO` in the root
  |
help: a similar name exists in the module
  |
4 |     mach_msg_type_number_t, mach_timebase_info_data_t, mach_task_self, task_info, task_info_t, KERN_SUCCESS,
  |                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
help: a similar name exists in the module
  |
4 |     mach_msg_type_number_t, mach_task_basic_info_data_t, mach_host_self, task_info, task_info_t, KERN_SUCCESS,
  |                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `memory-stats` (lib) due to previous error
```

Here is my rustc version:
rustc 1.72.1 (d5c2e9c34 2023-09-13)
and cargo version:
cargo 1.72.1 (103a7ff2e 2023-08-15)

Comment: Is this possibly a bug in that package?

Comment: I've just checked and it builds for me. What platform are you using?

Comment: Is your goal to track the memory usage from within the program or from the outside?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and helping me edit the typo. I want to track the memory usage within the program. I run the program on MacOS 13 with a M2 chip.